# What is the VSCode UI Font?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, fonts

Just to be clear, I'm aware I can customise the font used in the editor window of VSCode to just about any monospaced font I like. I am not asking about what font is used in the editor. I am asking if anyone knows what font is being used by VSCode for the rest of its interface?

I appreciate this is an unusual design question. But it's to do with my IDE and I need to confirm for a theme project I'm maintaining.

Cheers,

Comment: So, I've learnt a lot about VSCode in the last hour and managed to toggle the Dev Tools. The CSS says `font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, sans-serif;`. Does anyone know what font `-apple-system` or `system-ui` represent in the context of Mac OS? developer.apple mentions `SF Pro`. But there is also `SF UI Text` that is available and looks like it might be correct. Can anyone help me confirm, or explain to me how I might be able to confirm? Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to more docs, some trial and error, and even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface)) I can confirm that the font used in VSCode's own interface is **SF Pro** when running on Mac OS. I'm assuming that it is *SF Pro Text* and not *SF Pro Display*, given the use case. I've reversed engineered the interface during theme development in order to help determine.

[image: Wikipedia]